# COPY CSV TO POSTGRES TEXTX FIELDS ARE QUOTED

Tags: postgresql, csv, copy

I need to convert csv into postgres table. I using the query below:

```
copy public.itens_2019 from 'C:\itens.csv' delimiter ',' CSV HEADER;
```

```
108,62,'C','Falência de Empresários, Sociedades Empresáriais, Microempresas e Empresas de Pequeno Porte','A',,,,
```

it is possible to observe that the texts are enclosed in quotation marks, because the text has commas. This way I am not able to extract the columns correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with the below command

`copy public.itens_2019 from 'C:\itens.csv' delimiter ',' CSV HEADER QUOTE '''';`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below query for specific column. 
`copy table_name(column1,column2,column3,column4,column5) from 'C:\itens.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV;`